# Python kivy RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to create a simple app with kivy in python
but when i run this code i get following error
**RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison**

```
import wikipedia
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class GridLayout(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GridLayout, self).__init__()
         # Number of columns
        self.cols = 1
         

         # Second grid Layout
        self.second_layout = GridLayout()
        self.second_layout.cols = 2

        # Creating a text field to show the result of entered query
        self.query_result = TextInput(text='', size_hint_y=0.8)
        self.second_layout.add_widget(self.query_result)  # Adding query result on the screen

        # Creating a text input field to get the query from user
        self.query = TextInput(text='', multiline=False, hint_text="Enter your Query", size_hint_y=0.1, font_size=20)
        self.second_layout.add_widget(self.query)


        # Adding Second layout on the screen
        self.add_widget(second_layout)


        # Creating a submit button
        self.submit_button = Button(text="Submit", size_hint_y=0.1, font_size=40, on_press=self.submit)
        self.add_widget(self.submit_button)

        def submit(self, instance):
            try:
               query_result_from_wikipedia = wikipedia.page(self.query.text).summary
               self.query_result.text = query_result_from_wikipedia
            except:
               popup = Popup(title='Query Not Found',
                      content=Label(text='Try to Search Anything else'),
                      size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
               popup.open()


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GridLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

But when i remove the second gridlayout from it it runs without errors

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is the name of your class. Don't name a class the same as its subclass:

```
class GridLayout(GridLayout):
```

is likely to cause problems. Just change it to something like:

```
class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
```